# How can I speed up a MySQL product search result?

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a query on an mysql database based on typed data sent from a jquery autocomplete function. It works fine but take several seconds (5-6+) to get the returned suggestions. There are around 200,000 product entries in the database currently which is expected to go to well over a million entries. How can I speed this thing up, as once more entries are added, it stands to reason that the results would likely never show before someone has already typed in the full search query, which does not benefit them at all.

The MySQL tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `category` int(12) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `products_pics` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` int(12) NOT NULL default '0',
  `thumb` blob NOT NULL,
  `image` longblob NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(6) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The PHP code for the search and result return is:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['queryString'])) {
 $queryString = addslashes($_REQUEST['queryString']);
 if(strlen($queryString) > 0) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ORDER BY name LIMIT 8", $db);
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products_pics WHERE product_id='$myrow[id]' LIMIT 1", $db);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
        echo '<a href=""><img src="/ajax/search_images.php?id=' . $myrow[id] . '" width="55" border="0" alt="" />';
        }
        else {
        echo '<a href=""><img src="/images/items/no-img.jpg" width="55" border="0" alt="" />';
        }
        $name = stripslashes($myrow[name]);
        if(strlen($name) > 35) { 
         $name = substr($name, 0, 35) . "...";
        }             
        echo '<span class="searchheading">' . $name . '</span>';
        $description = stripslashes($myrow[description]);
        if(strlen($description) > 80) { 
         $description = substr($description, 0, 80) . "...";
        }
        echo '<span>' . $description . '</span></a>';
       }
       echo '<span class="seperator"></span>';
   } 
  }
 }
```

Thanks again guys, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you leave out, the image part in your loop, how is the speed then?

Comment: The `SELECT` in the loop is very simple and should be extremely fast. There's a `LIMIT 8` on the first query so it's only doing 8 `SELECT`s.

Comment: I still suspect it's the other query - seeing that his product image table contains binary data, his 8 products actually initiates 16 SQL queries - one for each product(8) and I assume that /ajax/search_images.php equally has at least one query for each image(8 again).

Comment: Repox, that well could be the issue, yes the search_images.php does 1 call for each of the 8 images, however I have added an index for product_id, so would assume that is about as fast as that can be pulled, am I missing something? hmm, maybe adding a default product image id to the products table?

Comment: use database indexing as well as following others suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `LIKE %keyword%` is very slow. Because you are doing autocomplete you could discard the first `%`, doing: `LIKE keyword%`.

That will speed up your query dramatically.

Also, try to execute your query in MYSQL like 'EXPLAIN <>'. This will provide you with info on how MySQL executes your query and where you might optimize.

Another option might be to use MyISAM's FULL TEXT SEARCH capability: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: "That will speed up your query dramatically. " --- only if he has `keyword` covered with index. But he has not.

Comment: zerkms: there is an index on the name field that the script would be searching for 'keyword' in.

Comment: This worked for me, switching to full text searches and index rather than doing the LIKE search, in conjunction with the comment by Repox giving me the idea to add a default image id to the products table, rather than calling the products_pics table 8 times per search. Results now show in less than 1 second.  Thanks both of you  :)